# How can I create 4 atoms basis graphene in Vesta?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, computational-physics, software, graphene

How can I create 4 atoms [basis graphene in Vesta](https://graphene.tube/2020/11/24/building-the-crystal-structure-of-graphene-in-vesta/)?

This is the [Poscar file](https://file.org/extension/poscar) for [two atoms basis graphene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphene#Electronic).

As an example. Similar to these I got to make a 4 atoms basis graphene primitive cell.

graphene
1.0
2.4549 0.000000000 0.0000000
-1.227445 2.126005764 0.0000000
0.000000000 0.000000000 12.0000000
C
2
Direct
0.00000 0.00000 0.00000
0.33333 0.66667 0.00000

Comment: Probably, the matter modeling stackexchange would be a better place to ask these kinds of questions.